# Get user's name from LDAP PHP

Tags: php, web, authentication, ldap

I need to retrieve my user's name to set a variable and use it to have a better welcome to the user.

Example: Login with `luis.lino` and it set $name = `"Luis Lino"` where `Luis Lino` is retrieved from AD through LDAP.

As so I can do "Welcome Luis Lino, we hope you enjoy your time in here"

I am using this code:

```
$myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']) . "@domain.com";
        $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 
        $local = $_POST['filial'];
        $ldap = ldap_connect("ldap://domain.com");
        if ($bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $myusername, $mypassword)) 
        {
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
            $filter = "(&(sAMAccountName={$myusername}))";
            $ldap_dn = "dc=domain.com";
            $attr = array("givenname");
            $result = ldap_search($ldap, $ldap_dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
            $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
            $givenname = $entries[0]['givenname'][0];
            ldap_unbind($ldap);

            setcookie("name", $givenname, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");  

            setcookie("sessao", $local, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 dia
            header("location: welcome.php");
        }
```

If I just use the "login" part it works perfectly, but with the above code I get the following error:

```
Warning: ldap_search(): Search: Client Loop in C:\wamp\www\OperPHP\index.php on line 20
```

I already looked into lots of posts but none solved my problem, anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try changing the following for connecting to LDAP (just need the additions below `ldap_connect()`:

```
$ldap = ldap_connect("ldap://domain.com");
// Set to LDAPv3 protocol, disable referrals...
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
```

Based on the error you're getting, it seems like it's stuck trying to do a referral. Also, your filter could be simplified to `$filter = "(sAMAccountName={$myusername})";`. I'm also not sure if this is just due to the example you're giving, but typically you want the base DN (`$ldap_dn` in your case) to be like this: `$ldap_dn = "dc=domain,dc=com";`.